# SQL Server 2012 stop working after specific time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012 stops working after every 6 to 7 hours, SQL Server Management Studio not connected, almost every service related to SQL Server stops, after system restart every service is working fine, I have got error in event window

```
   OpenSQLServerInstanceRegKey:GetRegKeyAccessMask failed (reason: 2).
```

[image]

SQL Server Agent log error

[image]

Sql server Log
[image]

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: OpenSQLServerInstanceRegKey:GetRegKeyAccessMask failed (reason: 2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916982/opensqlserverinstanceregkeygetregkeyaccessmask-failed-reason-2

Comment: @jurez question update

Comment: All those messages are from SQL Server Agent. You don't need Agent unless you have some scheduled jobs. Look at the SQL Server message logs instead.

Comment: To check SQL Server error messages connect to your instance and go to `Management > SQL Server Logs`. Also, the first print on your question has an error message related to failover. Is it a SQL Server cluster? If so, can you verify the logs for the cluster?

Comment: @Ronaldo question updated , sql server log attached

Comment: @Ronaldo no sql server cluster

Comment: check the SQL Server log for errors right before the instance stopped. The messages you added seems to be just the logins failing to connect on the instance that is no longer working properly and they all point to an error that occurred earlier. No cluster?! Your first print shows a failover and the SQL Server log at 3:34:06 has a msg about mirroring.

Comment: Not using any mirroring and clustering, sql server log show in jpg just before the sql server stopped. At 3:34 service stopped again

Comment: You need to look earlier in the logs to see what happened. Also, you can see a bunch of changes to advanced settings & stuff. It doesn't look like just some random shut down. It looks like something is actively doing something funky. Still, hard to say without the earlier logs.

Comment: Agreed (with Grant). We absolutely need the messages that caused the shutdown.